# Angular proxy error for external public API

Tags: angular, proxy

I have an angular application that is requiring public IP of client.
I successfully added a proxy to retrieve public IP as following:

```
  {
    "/jsonip": {
      "target": "https://jsonip.com",
      "secure": true,
      "changeOrigin": true
    }
  }
```

I also added this file in angular.json

```
    "browserTarget": "ProjectName:build",
    "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
```

When I'm trying to call this API, I got an error only when the application is on production (not on localhost)

```
    this.http.get(`${environment.WEBSITE_URL}/jsonip`, {headers: headers}).subscribe(
      (value:any) => {
        this.ipAddress = value.ip;
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

I also tried to add 'Origin' header to my request, but Chrome doesn't allow this.
How can I retrieve the result https://jsonip.com for client side without 404 ?

Answer (score 0):

Proxy configuration can only be done in development mode not production. t
That's why this option is there only in serve configuration not build.

Reference :- https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server